# How patches are created in Dictionary learning

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

How do we calculate image patches of a gray image. How is the size of the patch calculated? How many patches are needed to be calculated? Please explain and if possible give some links.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the patch size as you want. The only thing that is important is that your patch size of the patch offing process agrees with the patch size of your dictionary atoms. You could Ebene have whole images as atoms and no patches. However, with patches you get more “versatile” atoms, meaning that you can perform a much more detailed linear combination, when you have a sparse code. I suggest to watch some videos on YouTube (just search for sparse coding dictionary learning). You don’t need to calculate the patch size.